# Javascript Error while opening Infopath templates from within .Net webbrowser control on 64-bit Vista machines

Tags: sharepoint, windows-vista, 64-bit, richtextbox, infopath

We have some browser enabled **Infopath 2007** templates hosted on Windows **Sharepoint** server (Windows 2003 machines). We use a couple of 'Rich Textboxes' in these templates and these templates are made available to the end user via .Net windows application that used the WebBrowser control.

The application runs just fine, but only on 64-bit machines with **64-bit Vista** installed Javascript exceptions are being thrown ("Stylesheet" is null or not an object OR "body" is null or not an object) when clicking on the **rich textboxes**.

Comment: It's good to know it's not just me, I'm currently seeing the same issue using InfoPath Forms Services from 64bit installs of Windows 7. Our servers are Windows 2008/IIS 7, so it's not just a symptom of SharePoint on Windows 2003 if it helps anyone track down the problem.

Comment: May be better on serverfault?

Comment: This is not server related, it is clearly a client compatability issue. Gave my 2 cents below but voted to move to superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Although this belongs on superuser, here's my 2 cents.

- Have you tried running a debug session in the Javascript console of IE. See which line in which file generates the error. (access the js console by pressing F12, set a breakpoint somewhere at the top of the file in a piece of SP / ASP.NET generated JS code, then press F5, it should stop at the error you are getting)
- Are all updates installed? SP2 especially addresses a lot of browser compatibility issues.
- Does the error occur in both the IE8 standard (32 bit) and the extra link under all programs for IE8 (64 bit)?